# Mysql stored procedure with table name as parameter

Tags: mysql, database

I am writing stored procedure where one of the parameters is the name of the table from which i want to execute a query and do some math on the resultset.

Unfortunatelly i can not make it works when the table name is not hardcoded into the select statement.

I found another solution using prepared statement but unfortunatelly i do not know how to get the cursor to iterate throught the result and do some calculations.

Any idea?

Comment: The prepared statement is the way to go here, could you share your best effort with that solution, so we can see where the iteration goes awry?

Comment: How can i iterate throught the prepared statment inside the stored procedure?